# cant get array in class A to work in class B

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a java project. When i first started i had a lot of code in one java class. this was starting to become really messy so i tried to spread the code into other classes. this is where i get got a problem with an array.

i made a class that creates the array, the array has one getter method so my main class can use it.

```
public class CreateBlockArray {

private static int[][][] blockarray;


public CreateBlockArray(){

//get coordinates 

    //fill array        
    int[][][] blockarray = new int[Xdelta+ 10][Ydelta + 10][Zdelta + 10];

    blockarray = fillarray(Xlow,Ylow, Zlow, Xhigh, Yhigh, Zhigh, blockarray   );
    blockarray = getvisibleBlocks(Xlow,Ylow, Zlow, Xhigh, Yhigh, Zhigh, blockarray);    
    blockarray = filloceanfloor(Xlow,Ylow, Zlow, Xhigh, Yhigh, Zhigh, blockarray);  
    //these three methods modify array and than return it

}


public int[][][] getBlockarray() {
    return blockarray;
}
```

in the main class i use this

```
CreateBlockArray Array = new CreateBlockArray();
int[][][] blockarray = Array.getBlockarray();
//more code
if (blockarray[i][k][j] != 0) //it crashes here
```

this gives a null pointer exception.
from similair questions on stackoverflow i understood that the array is not a primitive but a reference.

so i tried simply copying the array block by block with this code

```
blockarray2 = new int[(Xhigh-Xlow)+10][(Yhigh-Ylow)+10][(Zhigh-Zlow) +10];
    for(int h = Ylow;  h <= Yhigh;h++)
    {
    for(int i = Xlow;  i <= Xhigh;i++)
    {           
    for(int j = Zlow;  j <= Zhigh;j++)
    {                           

        blockarray2[i-Xlow][h-Ylow][j-Zlow] = blockarray[i-Xlow][h-Ylow][j-Zlow];

    }}}
```

when i return this everything works fine and i get no errors.
can i also return the first array without having to copy it?

Comment: a) please post the concrete exception message b) please format your code properly (especially the three nested `for` loops)

Comment: Why do you have a *`static`* array declared which you are populating on *object instantiation*?  There's a very strong smell with this code...is it the case that each method you use to reassign the value of `blockarray` is merely passing it along to one another and the values are actually being filled in?

Comment: @brso05:  I can see that, but that wasn't what I was alluding to.  The *intent* was to initialize the static array when the class was instantiated.  This means that if he declares `new CreateBlockArray()` anywhere else, presto - they've got a brand new 3D array and they may not have wanted that.  This is why it smells.

Comment: @Makoto: i only need one array and dont need any copies and every change i make needs to get saved. I am not a java expert but i thought the static identifier only allows one object to be created and no more. btw the array is a huge array for example 200 * 200 * 200 or even 1000 * 1000 * 100 so i dont want dead copies. and yes the array starts of empty and each method fills it in or deletes unneeded values

Comment: Well, that's a fair misconception.  Jean's answer suits you well, but know that a field declared `static` means that only one instance exists across all classes.  What I was pointing out was that if you were to instantiate that class again, you'd wipe out your existing array which isn't desirable.

Comment: Had not thought about that.Luckily i only need it once after creating it in the class, after that no more changes are made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in this constructor :

```
public CreateBlockArray(){

//get coordinates 

    //fill array        
    int[][][] blockarray = new int[Xdelta+ 10][Ydelta + 10][Zdelta + 10];

    blockarray = fillarray(Xlow,Ylow, Zlow, Xhigh, Yhigh, Zhigh, blockarray   );
    blockarray = getvisibleBlocks(Xlow,Ylow, Zlow, Xhigh, Yhigh, Zhigh, blockarray);    
    blockarray = filloceanfloor(Xlow,Ylow, Zlow, Xhigh, Yhigh, Zhigh, blockarray);  
    //these three methods modify array and than return it

}
```

You are not really modifying the `blockarray` of the class as you re-declare it in the method :

```
int[][][] blockarray = new int[Xdelta+ 10][Ydelta + 10][Zdelta + 10];
```

just change that line for

```
blockarray = new int[Xdelta+ 10][Ydelta + 10][Zdelta + 10];
```

and remove the `static` identifier in that line :

```
private static int[][][] blockarray;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you declare your array:

```
private static int[][][] blockarray;
```

But in the constructor, you declare it again as a local variable:

```
int[][][] blockarray = new int[Xdelta+ 10][Ydelta + 10][Zdelta + 10];
```

So all your operations are done on the local array rather than the field.

Avoid declaring it again, just write

```
blockarray = new int[Xdelta+ 10][Ydelta + 10][Zdelta + 10];
```

inside the constructor, and then it will use the field.

Also, of course, if you want an array to be part of the state of a class, it must not be declared as static, or there will be just one array shared between all instances of that class. Perhaps you don't need a constructor at all, just a static initialization block.

Comment: what you mean with a static initialization block? i only want to build array in a seperate class and to use it in another for one time only. after that it can be deleted.

Comment: @Lethalbeast - Frankly, I think your break up of the code is probably incorrect. Data should be in the same class as the methods that use it. Breaking into classes should be done by finding some operations that work on the same data and are relatively independent of other data. I could add an example of a static block if I knew where your `Xdelta` etc. are coming from because they are not declared anywhere in your OP.

Comment: the array is used for saving all block ID's from minecraft blocks in a certain region. the array is later being used to convert it into a .map file which is used for making gamemaps with the quake3 engine in my case Call of Duty 4. but before i can use array i need to sort out all unneeded blocks which are not visible and blocks i dont want. so this array takes a lot of code space therefore i think it deserves its own class. the Xdelta,Ydelta,Zdelta are the distances between two coordinates and  the size of the array.